# Propagate Event from internal component

Tags: delphi, events

I'm writing a component that include few components.

```
TMyComponent = class(TPanel)
  private
    fGrid : TExCustomDBGrid;
    fOnCellClick : TDBGridClickEvent;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  published
    property OnCellClick: TDBGridClickEvent read FOnCellClick write FOnCellClick;
  End;
...
constructor TMyComponent .Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fGrid := TExCustomDBGrid.Create(self);
  fGrid.parent := self;
  fGrid.Align := alClient;
end;
```

I want to be able to propagate the Event from the component (TPanel), to the fGrid included.
How can I reach that goal ?

I guess I should declare an Event with the same type on the TPanel (as container component). Then how to propagate into the fGrid ?

Comment: I'm assuming my answer is what you were looking for, but it's a bit confusing that you seem to be describing the propagation backwards. You don't propagate from the panel to the grid, but rather the grid to the panel.

Comment: You are right. In fact... i want to have an event in my TPanel that will be called after the DBGrid.OnCellClick event will be raized. To execute the code i put in my TPanel.OncellClick Event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but based on the code I see, write an event handler and assign it to the grid...

```
procedure TMyComponent.DBGridCellClicked(Column: TColumn);
begin
  if Assigned(fOnCellClick) then
    fOnCellClick(Column);
end;

constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  fGrid := TExCustomDBGrid.Create(self);
  fGrid.Parent := self;
  fGrid.Align := alClient;
  fGrid.OnCellClick := DBGridCellClicked;
end;
```